# Primitive types slower than user types in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, profiling, primitive-types, usertype

I was curious and did a little benchmark to determine the performance delta between primitive types such as `int` or `float` and user types.

I created a template class `Var`, created some inline arithmetic operators. The test consisted of looping this loop for both the primitive and `Var` vectors:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    in1[i] = i;
    in2[i] = -i;
    out[i] = (i % 2) ? in1[i] + in2[i] : in2[i] - in1[i];
}
```

I was quite surprised with the results, turns out my `Var` class is faster most of the time, with int on average that loop took about 5700 nsec less with the class. Out of 3000 runs, int was faster 11 times vs. `Var` which was faster 2989 times. Similar results with `float`, where `Var` is 15100 nsec faster than floatin 2991 of the runs.

Shouldn't primitive types be faster?

Edit: Compiler is a rather ancient mingw 4.4.0, build options are the defaults of QtCreator, no optimizations:

```
qmake call: qmake.exe C:\...\untitled15.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=release"
```

OK, posting full source, platform is 64 bit Win7, 4 GB DDR2-800, Core2Duo@3Ghz

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QVector>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

template<typename T>
class Var{
public:
    Var() {}
    Var(T val) : var(val) {}

    inline T operator+(Var& other)
    {
        return var + other.value();
    }

    inline T operator-(Var& other)
    {
        return var - other.value();
    }

    inline T operator+(T& other)
    {
        return var + other;
    }

    inline T operator-(T& other)
    {
        return var - other;
    }

    inline void operator=(T& other)
    {
        var = other;
    }

    inline T& value()
    {
        return var;
    }

private:
    T var;
};

int main()
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    QElapsedTimer timer;

    unsigned count = 1000000;

    QVector<double> pin1(count), pin2(count), pout(count);
    QVector<Var<double> > vin1(count), vin2(count), vout(count);

    unsigned t1, t2, pAcc = 0, vAcc = 0, repeat = 10, pcount = 0, vcount = 0, ecount = 0;
    for (int cc = 0; cc < 5; ++cc)
    {
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < repeat; ++c)
        {
            timer.restart();
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                pin1[i] = i;
                pin2[i] = -i;
                pout[i] = (i % 2) ? pin1[i] + pin2[i] : pin2[i] - pin1[i];
            }
            t1 = timer.nsecsElapsed();
            cout << t1 << endl;

            timer.restart();
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                vin1[i] = i;
                vin2[i] = -i;
                vout[i] = (i % 2) ? vin1[i] + vin2[i] : vin2[i] - vin1[i];
            }
            t2 = timer.nsecsElapsed();
            cout << t2 << endl;;
            pAcc += t1;
            vAcc += t2;
        }

        pAcc /= repeat;
        vAcc /= repeat;
        if (pAcc < vAcc) {
            cout << "primitive was faster" << endl;
            pcount++;
        }
        else if (pAcc > vAcc) {
            cout << "var was faster" << endl;
            vcount++;
        }
        else {
            cout << "amazingly, both are equally fast" << endl;
            ecount++;
        }

        cout << "Average for primitive type is " << pAcc << ", average for Var is " << vAcc << endl;

    }
    cout << "int was faster " << pcount << " times, var was faster " << vcount << " times, equal " << ecount << " times, " << pcount + vcount + ecount << " times ran total" << endl;
}
```

Relatively, with floats the Var class is 6-7% faster than floats, with ints about 3%.

I also ran the test with vector length of 10 000 000 instead of the original 1000 and results are still consistent and in favor of the class.

Comment: Please, add the compiler and build options. And the Var implementation, also.

Comment: and compare the assembler code.

Comment: Depending on how you measure, this loop may run in (much) too short time to yield precise or repeatable performance data.

Comment: Also, 5700ns or 15100ns out of how much in total? A relative comparison is missing. What platform are you measuring on? Aka @Forgottn compiler question. What time measurement method are you using on that platform?

Comment: Did you test the `int` version first and the class version second within the same run? That could absolutely skew the results if anything was cached.

Comment: @PeterG. - the test runs 3000 times in about 30 seconds, this should be enough to minimize margin of error.

Comment: @pmr - what exactly do you mean? The + operator for a Var<int> is resolved to int + int?

Comment: @ddriver: This is quite possible due to promotions. For `float` all intermediate values are computed by converting them to `double`. `int` however is the promoted to data type for all integral types -- so this is optimal (against any of `char`, `long` etc.). Try with `double` and let us know the results you get.

Comment: @dirkgently - just tested with a vector of 10 000 000 doubles, Var<double> takes 191895368 nsec on average. double takes 207335291 nsec on average, across 10 runs, thats about 8% faster for Var.

Comment: Are you timing the declaration of the array?  Your class version zeros each value at construction, where the POD types do not.  That pulls the memory into cache, so the subsequent loops will be faster.  Try memsetting your POD arrays to 0 _outside_ the timing loop for an equivalent test case.

Comment: @ddriver: Okay, about time we see the source! (Also, compiler/platform info as others have noted.)

Comment: What types of in1 and in2 arrays? Are you using both types in single loop?

Comment: @Peter - removed zeroing, added the full source via an edit.

Comment: Maybe it's optimization issue, can you put arrays declaration before main and mark them as volatile.
And also what the difference in DEBUG mode?

Comment: @victor.t - in debug mode, primitive types win full out, with about double the performance for double and about 30% faster for ints

Comment: Did you tried to put vectors as global variables and mark them as volatile in release mode?

Comment: @victor.t - I tried, but I get an error when I try to resize the vectors in main - passing 'volatile QVector<int>' as 'this' argument of 'void QVector<T>::resize(int) [with T = int]' discards qualifiers

Comment: try to make all vectors as global variables it should prevent compiler from "optimizing" the loops

Comment: Why would anyone try to profile for performance with no optimization?

Comment: Because one of the loop could be removed by compiled due "no-use" scenario.

Comment: @victor.t - making the vectors global didn't change performance, now checking with raw arrays to eliminate effects of the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `QVector` replaced by `std::vector`, at `-O2` optimization level, code generated by GCC for the two types is exactly the same, instruction for instruction.

Without the replacement, the generated code is different, but that's hardly surprising, considering that `QtVector` is implemented differently for primitive and non-primitive types (look for `QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex` in `qvector.h`).

**Update** It looks like `isComplex` does not affect the linner oop, i.e. the measured part. The loop code still differs for the two types, albeit very slightly. It looks like the difference is due to GCC.

Comment: I've tested with std::vector and also with a raw, c-style array, with standard vectors performance is a little in favor of the primitive types, with raw arrays the situation is reversed

Answer (score 0):

I benchmarked running time and memory allocation for QVector and float* with very little difference between both